# "Do you have any plan..."

Tags: grammar

> Do you have any plan...
>
> A. **for going** to law school?
>   B. **to go** to law school?
>   C. **of going** to law school?

Comment: What is the question here? A and B mean different things. What is the sentence trying to say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A, B, and C are all acceptable.  The Ngram viewer finds uses of all three prepositions after the noun plan.  "Of" is preferred in the following circumstances:

- In the idiom "**plan of** attack"
- In referring to blueprints, "a **plan of** the second floor"
- For the owner of the plan, "the **plan of** God for my life"
- In the US bankruptcy law term of art, "**plan of** reorganization"